# Extruding edges using set position node and geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

Extruding edges using set position node and geometry nodes

I'm trying to get the edges to extrude straight up but they go out at an angle.

When I extrude the top edges (using the set position node) they don't go straight up.

**The things I've tried:**

1. Used the scale elements node to scale just the top edges back in to force them to be straight.
   (Strange effects)
2. I tried using the Align Euler to Vector node.
   (Strange effects)

[image: img1]

Attached file below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i hope you don't mind, but why don't you use just the extrude mesh node?

like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! Honestly I did try that I just didn't touch the offset attribute (didn't really know it could do that)...your magic touch was adding the combine xyz node to the offset attribute.

Comment: you are welcome. And honestly...i don't know either how to do it with set position ;)